# I can't hide my object in the UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason when I try to call

```
  renderer.enabled = false;
```

on a label contained in the UI, I get no warning but nothing happens.

I also tried to use SetActive or change the active property directly but unity doesn't recognize it, it will not autocomplete, and will show an error there.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: If you want to hide label 'renderer' then use `renderer.Visible=false;`

Comment: It doesn't recognize "visible" neither

Comment: Just want to make sure, are you using 'Visible' (case-sensitive)?

Comment: Is it new Unity UI?

Comment: The property is `enabled`, not `enable`, don't know if that is just a typo in your question. Otherwise I'd suggest to call `SetActive` on the gameobject the renderer is part of (if you use the new UI).

Comment: Just a typo sorry but thanks to have pointed it out. I'm not sure of the exact version of the UI, I didn't know it would actually make a difference on this. I'll check this out thanks.

Comment: The thing is, when I tried it on a basic cube which is not part of the UI, it does exactly the same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;` to disable a GameObject's Renderer component. This will mean the Renderer simply does not render the GameObject. Unity docs for `Renderer.enabled` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-enabled.html).

If you want to make the UI element invisible you could add a [Canvas Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) component to it and set the Alpha channel to 0. This makes the element (and any of its children) 100% transparent.

Comment: I still can't figure out what's wrong with my scene but I'll probably go for the Alpha alternative if I'm stuck with it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rendrer attcahed to UI Component so it will always give you error , if you want to hide it or show it .. access it as gameobject using label.gameobject.SetActive(true/false).

Hope it helps

Comment: I guess if I disable the 'active' variable, the attached scripts won't keep running until the component is re-enabled.
I need it though, but it's also another way of doing it if you have other purposes.

Comment: you can always access it from another script as a public reference gameobject and do whatever you want from there